# Access output files of Random Forrest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am new with R.
I have read the manual of random forest:
V3.1 (https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/Using_random_forests_V3.1.pdf)
V4.0 (https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/Using_random_forests_v4.0.pdf)
Both manuals have mentioned several times about saving outputs into a 'file'. My question is, how can I actually access to the 'file'?

For example, the V3.1 manual said I can set `impstd=1` to "computes and prints the following columns to a 'File", how can I view the file? What are the file path and the format of the file?

Similarly I am interested to access to the file for the following functions:
`impgraph=1`, `isavef=1` and `isavep=1`, etc.

Thanks.
Here is my dataset: I use the train data here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Here is my R Scipt:
`rf_model <- randomForest(factor(Survived) ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked, data = train, method="repeatcv", number=5, repeats=10, maxnode=8, impgraph=1)`

where `impgraph=1` gives for each variable, a plot of the effect of
the variable on the class probabilities

How can I find the plot? Similary, if I add `infoutr=1` in the function, how can I view the output file?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Hey there, you are more likely to get a useful answer if you put a sample of data (using `dput(df)` )where `df `is your data frame or one of fake data for the example, and some code running your random forrest and an example of what you would like, or a link to some kind of output which has the sort of content you are looking for from the summary. This is too enigmatic to get where you where you need to be!

Comment: Welcome.. Please read and follow: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Generally you'll need to include an [MVE: Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can click `edit` to edit your question and improve your chances of getting an answer.  Also, if the question to too broad, or does not have enough info, it may be deleted by SO. All the best.

Comment: Hi sconfluentus and SherylHohman,

Thanks. I revise my question now.

Comment: Although the reference papers that you discuss are on random forest implementation in Fortran language, you used an R tag for this question. R has its own implementation of random forests that is based on Breiman's (et al.) work. The resource to go to in R is the radnomForest package and its documentation. There you can research the initial answers for your question and come back with specific ones.

Comment: Hi Patrick,
Yes. I have already check this and, actually if I understand this correctly, I was redirected to the link of the v3.1 manual when searching the `randomForest` function under the HELP session. 
I apologise if I still did not make my question clear. If this does, please remove my question and I will try other means to work this out. Thanks again for your assistance.